# Breadcrumbs with action menu - what are the best practices?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I am curious about best practices for visualizing additional actions in breadrumbs.

**Details:** the user should be able to copy the IDs of the elements from the breadcrumbs.

Is it a good way to add such a solution as in the screenshot? Or is it better to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Do you still have the navigation function as well? I feel like users would be confused if they are trying to use breadcrumbs in the standard way (navigation) and end up only having the option to copy

Answer (score 1):

### Breadcrumb Dropdowns

There are many examples on the internet like the one in the [this page](https://avadathe.me/customization/user-friendly-navigation-breadcrumb-dropdown/) menu. The difference with the example in the question is that they are used for navigation, the primary function of a breadcrumb, not for an action like copying an element (At least I haven't seen it, Google: *[breadcrumb dropdown](https://www.google.com/search?q=breadcrumb%20dropdown&source=lmns&bih=1228&biw=1485&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-64bEsP75AhUGQhoKHdiBD2MQ_AUoAHoECAEQAA)*).

[image]

<sub>*Image source [processwire.com](https://processwire.com/modules/breadcrumb-dropdowns/)*</sub>

However, I think the action can be implemented within the breadcrumb item, I would try making it clear that it is something separate from the navigation <kbd>></kbd>

[image]